# Android change edittext background

Tags: android, multithreading, background, android-edittext

I have an EditText (et) and a button (bt). When I press bt, et should change the background color to green, and after 1 second return white.
My code is something like this:

```
    bt.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            answer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){}
            answer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        }
    });
```

The problem that I noticed is that the color of et changes only when the code is completely executed, not when the method is called! In other words, et is always white, because the change to green never happens.
Is there an alternative to that code? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: try to only set it green? does it work? Start A runnable with a `handler.postdelayed(runnable, 1000)` to start another action in 1second! You should never use Thread.sleep!

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
 bt.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View view){
                                        answer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
                                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                    answer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                                            }
                                        }, 1000);
                                    }
                                });
```

Comment: Now it works! Thank you very much, I've spent hours on this problem!